# How to flush StringIO() in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout

I am trying to redirect output, and flush every once in a while to clear the buffer.

Flushing doesn't do anything - can't even enter the function with debugger.

```
from io import BytesIO as StringIO

out = StringIO()
out.write("hi")
output = out.getvalue().strip()
assert output == "hi"
out.flush()
output = out.getvalue().strip()
assert output == ""
```

The second assertion fails, as output is still "hi". `flush()` did nothing.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do one change, Replace **out.flush()** with **out.truncate(0)** and then it will be work fine as follows:

```
from io import BytesIO as StringIO

out = StringIO()
out.write("hi")
output = out.getvalue().strip()
assert output == "hi"
out.seek(0)
out.truncate(0)
output = out.getvalue().strip()
assert output == ""
```

Comment: Having read the duplicate, For future compatibility best to also `out.seek(0)` before `.truncate(0)`

Comment: Yeah, It will be perfect.

Comment: edit your answer please so I will accept